# How to rollback message using transacted flag for camel-activemq-starter

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I am using camel-activemq-starter with yaml auto configuration. When I use "?transacted=true" flag on consumer, the message go to DLQ. The behavior I am looking for is not to remove message from the queue if there is an exception in camel route. This worked as expected using "transacted=true" flag with camel-sjms and camel-jms. Thank you in advance for your help! Below is yaml config.

```
camel:
  component:
    reactive-streams:
      thread-pool-max-size: 5
    activemq:
      broker-url: "tcp://localhost:61616"
      connection-factory: ActiveMQConnectionFactory
      transaction-manager: JmsTransactionManager
```

Below is how route looks like in gneral:

```
    fromF("activemq:queue:queue?transacted=true")
                    .routeId("stopThisRoute")
                    .process(exchange -> {
----- something ------
                    })
                    -------
                            throw new IllegalStateException();
========
                        })
                    .end();
```

Comment: That looks strange. Do you have a repo or could update the question with minimal reproducible sample?

Comment: I cannot imagine how this might work in `camel-jms` while not working in `camel-activemq`. `camel-activemq` just extends `camel-jms` with no additional endpoint or consumer logic. Please mention Camel version and reproducible sample would be great.

Comment: Camel version is 3.3.0. Please note that the message does go to DLQ but what I am looking for is the message stays in the queue. In camel-jms and camel-sjms, jut putting transacted=true keeps the message in the queue when there is exception.

Comment: @based on your last comment, it seems like that transacted flag is still working in activemq but it gets moved to DLQ. Did you check if it is present in that queue? If is the case, you want to update the question so

Comment: @ Kavithakaran, I have updated the question. Let me know if further clarification is needed.

Comment: Message is moved to DLQ by broker (In case of ActiveMQ by configuration `deadLetterStrategy` in `broker.xml`), not Camel. Camel only creates `SESSION_TRANSACTED` for `transacted=true` This is why I am still confused by statement `This worked as expected using "transacted=true" flag with camel-sjms and camel-jms`. You have really tested both components connected to the exactly same instance and queue of ActiveMQ and the behavior was different?

Comment: yes, that is correct. the behavior is different. In camel-sjms though, I had different configuration in yaml file to use Spring-activemq auo config. But the transacted code did not pull the message off the queue if there was an exception in route.

Comment: @user3549576, I doubt your explanation of it stayed in the same queue for `camel-jms`. The reason dead letter queue exists is to avoid poisonous messages stopping the consumer from consuming good messages. If a message that is going to fail all the time is put back to the queue repeatedly, your consumer will enter an infinite loop.  So may be in the case of `camel-sjms and camel-jms`, it was never consumed by your consumer in the first place

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai it seems the way camel-sjms worked is that it did not remove the message from the queue when transaction failed.

Comment: Can you remove `throw new IllegalStateException();` and see `camel-jms` consuming message successfully.  Because I think it is not consuming at all

Comment: @user3549576 did you get a chance to verify the last comment?

Comment: If the "throw" is not there, the message flows to next route and removed from queue as expected.

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai please see the fix I posted. It seems it was just a different behavior for rollback/ack between these plugins. Please comment on the posted answer your opinion on why it could be like this. thank you so much.

Comment: Good to know. that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding ack mode fixed this issue with camel-activemq-starter. Probably its not "issue" just a different behavior.

```
camel:
  component:
    activemq:
      broker-url: "tcp://localhost:61616"
      connection-factory: CachingConnectionFactory
      transacted: true
      transaction-manager: JmsTransactionManager
      acknowledgement-mode-name: CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE
```